# How to change default value for telerik RadSlider?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, slider

I've been Googleing but unable to find an answer. I have my slider from 1-10 and want the default value to be 10. Right now the slider starts at 0.

```
                <telerik:RadSlider runat="server" ID="RadSlider_Q1" Width="450px" Height="60px" MinimumValue="0"
                    MaximumValue="5" SelectionStart="0" SelectionEnd="5" TrackPosition="BottomRight"
                    ItemType="Item" Skin="Web20" Length="450">
                    <Items></Items>
                </telerik:RadSlider>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. From code behind

```
RadSliderID.SelectedIndex = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

use this cod:

> DbValue="your value as number"

example:

> telerik:RadSlider runat="server" ID="RadSlider_Q1" DbValue="10" ...